# Why is Range.Find() method so confusing?

Tags: excel, vba

This code gives me a 424 error "Object Required".

```
Dim playerLocation As Range
Set playerLocation = Sheets("World Map").UsedRange.Find("&").Address
```

And this works fine

```
Set playerLocation = Sheets("World Map").UsedRange.Find("&")
```

But when i put them into the immediate window:

```
?Sheets("World Map").UsedRange.Find("&").Address
$T$18
?Sheets("World Map").UsedRange.Find("&")
&
```

Is it just me or this completely backwords? Doesn't a Range variable take a range object? But it creates an error when i explicitly give it the Address of a cell. I'm so confused.

Comment: remove the `.Address` from the find line.  Find returns a range object.  `.Address` returns a string.

Comment: In the first bit you are trying to assign a string to a range - `address` is a property of the `range` object which returns a string. Hence the second bit is the correct approach.

Comment: as to why `?Sheets("World Map").UsedRange.Find("&")` returns `&`.  Remember that `.Value` is the default for a range object.  so the Find is returning a range object and the `?` is returning the default of `.Value`

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I didn't realize a range object was different from a string. I stand by this being extremely unintuitive

Comment: You just need to read up on the concept of the Excel object model.

Comment: @BreadDoughlas A `Range` is an Object - a House is also an object.  Like a `Range`, a House also has an `Address`.  You can live in a house, and you can fit the `Address` on an envelope - but not the other way around!

Answer (score 5):

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), Range.Find method:

> **Return value:**
>   A Range object that represents the first cell where that information is found.

However, the [Range.Address property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address):

> Returns a String value that represents the range reference in the language of the macro.

Perhaps one way of thinking about it, is that by using `.Address` explicitly, you're *asking* for a String. You're not asking for an Object (which `Range`) is.  If you were, you'd correctly declare your object and just leave off `.Address`.

And of course, you can always get the `Address` property from a `Range` Variable...`Dim findRng as Range // Set findRng = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find("something") // debug.print findRng.Address`.

You can also access [all other `Range` properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#properties) now, so when I personally need to use `Find`, I tend to set that as a `Range`, so I don't have to "work backwards" later if I want to, say bold the cell, etc.